# adding a method via prototype issue javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to add a property and method via prototype. I have my code in working order, but instead of having a property value based on user input, it shows bikeArray[0].color as undefined. I don't think I am calling the method function correctly, or I didn't define it correctly. I'm a bit confused, what am I doing wrong here.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="requirement_13">
    <h3>Requirment 13 - 14</h3>
    <p id="bike"></p>
    <ul id="speed_info">
        <li>Our bike gears can be customized to achieve certain speed possibilities.</li>
        <li>The standard gearing speed is 12mph.</li>
        <li>If you would like something different, please select a number below to either<br>
                add or subtract from max gear speed.</li>
        <li>We will handle the rest from there.<br></li>
    </ul>
    <form>      
    <input type="number" id="speed" min="-6" max="15" required>
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li> Our standard bike color is "Gun Metal Grey"</li>
        <li> You can select a bike color from below if<br>
            you wish to change the color.</li>
    </ul>
    <form id="bike_color">
        <select name="change_color:">
            <option value="Gun Metal Grey" selected>Gun Metal Grey</option>
            <option value="Cherry Red">Cherry Red</option>
            <option value="Sky Runner Blue">Sky Runner Blue</option>
            <option value="Rose Pink">Rose Pink</option>
            <option value="Plum Purpler">Plum Purpler</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="gear_submit" value="Submit" onclick="createBike();">
        <p id="show_bike"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//global bike array
var bikeArray = [];

function createBike() {
    function bike(model, speed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;

        // this will change speed based on user input
        this.changeSpeed = function (changeSpeed) {
            var new_speed = parseInt(document.getElementById("speed").value, 10);
            bikeArray[0].speed = speed + new_speed;
        }
    }

    var bike1 = new bike("Ghost Ryder", 12);
    bikeArray[0] = bike1;

    bike1.changeSpeed();

// add the color property and method to set the value of color
    bike.prototype.color;
    bike.prototype.color = function (colorPicker){
        var color = document.getElementsByName("change_color").value;
        bike1.color = color;    
     }

     bike1.color();

    document.getElementById("show_bike").innerHTML =
    bikeArray[0].model + " " + bikeArray[0].speed + " " + bikeArray[0].color;
}
```

my out put looks like this : Ghost Ryder 14 undefined

where undefined is, I need it to show the user selected color.

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPZwXO)

Comment: What part of the code returns `undefined ? Can you be more precise ?

Comment: the color property value returns undefined... Ill edit my post

Comment: What is the line `bike.prototype.color;` for?

Comment: there are several problems here, among them, your inline functions have defined arguments which are never received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have a typo in your select element name:

`<select name="change_color:">` needs to be `<select name="change_color">`, because that is how you reference it in the code.

Secondly `getElementsByName` returns a list of all elements with that name, so instead of:

```
document.getElementsByName("change_color").value
```

you need to use:

```
document.getElementsByName("change_color")[0].value
```

With those changes the color no longer displays as undefined.

**Updated, working CodePen:** http://codepen.io/maxlaumeister/pen/xwZbMG

Comment: ugh, was about to say it! Nice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some modified code:

```
var bikeArray = [];

function createBike() {
    function bike(model, speed) {
        this.model = model;
        this.speed = speed;

        // this will change speed based on user input
        this.changeSpeed = function () {
            var new_speed = 2; // just literal for simplicity
            bikeArray[0].speed = speed + new_speed;
        }
    }

    var bike1 = new bike("Ghost Ryder", 12);
    bikeArray[0] = bike1;

    bike1.changeSpeed();

    // add the color property and method to set the value of color
    bike.prototype.color = function (){
        var color = "green";// just literal for simplicity
        this.mycolor = color;    // use this, not bike1 and color is the function, don't override!
     }

     bike1.color();

    console.log(
    bikeArray[0].model + " " + bikeArray[0].speed + " " + bikeArray[0].mycolor);
}

createBike();
```